# Load text to speech during previous activity, advertisement, or splash screen

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

In my 'Main Activity' I use text to speech. However, it takes around four to five seconds to initialize. Is there a way that I could initialize text to speech while my splash screen and home screen activities are being shown? Or possibly when an advertisement is displayed? Any help would be appreciated. If not, are there any other ways to speed up the onCreate process? Many thanks!!!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
        String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.englishAnimalArray);
        String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();

        tts=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                            result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                        Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                    }
                    else{
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                            tts.speak(textViewString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        } else {
                            tts.speak(textViewString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/36013611/1256219